# \newmdtheoremenv environment without numbering without caption

Tags: mdframed

I would like to make a frame around content that breaks across pages. For that I use `mdframed` package.

Note that in that frame I also have `\section` and `\subsection` markers (because I am writing a research proposal for TUBITAK where all my content has to be put into a 1pt wide frame ... originally they use Microsoft Word with a single-column-single-row table where the row has a frame and can break across pages ... now I have to reproduce that in LaTeX because ... you know ... Word has no Biblatex and so on.

If I use `\begin{mdframed}` it works nice, but the frame is too thin. Using `\usepackage[linewidth=1pt]{mdframed}` did not work.

Now I tried to configure the frame to use a heavier line style with `\newmdtheoremenv`. Now I get compile errors for each `\section` and `\subsection` entry.

Do you have any ideas how I could avoid that?

If you have another idea for putting text into across-page-breakable frames or just for putting vertical lines besides text on the page I am also grateful. (I could then just add starting and finishing horizontal lines. mdframed makes footnotes frame-local so having an alternative solution would even be better.)

Comment: You can use `tcolorbox`. Are you willing?

Comment: I basically need any kind of content within the frame (I can put figures outside) and it has to break across pages. I will have a look if tcolorbox can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcolorbox` is more advanced and fancier for such jobs. Here is a simple example to get you started.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=1pt,colback=yellow!30,arc=0mm, breakable] %% you can add many more options if 
                                                                    %% you like.
\section{Some section}
\kant[1-5]
\subsection{A subsection}
\kant[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make it fancier and adjust dimensions etc. For details refer to the manual.

Comment: Thank you, it seems tcolorbox can really do everything I need. [I also found \tcbline that comes in very handy.]

Comment: Ah yes, and the `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` is a very crucial part of the example that I missed in my first attempts.

Comment: @peschü Once you start using `tcolorbox`, you won't leave it. It is very handy :)